# What is the purpose of `exec "$@"` in ros_entrypoint.sh?

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the Dockerfiles here: https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/tree/master/ros/indigo/indigo-ros-core, what is the purpose of `exec "$@"`, i.e., the last line in `ros_entrypoint.sh` ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241349/what-is-the-purpose-of-%60exec-%22$@%22%60-in-ros_entrypoint.sh-?/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`exec "$@"` causes the shell to exec the arguments that were passed in.

In this case, the ENTRYPOINT script is setting up the ROS environment and then executing the command that you gave it.

The [docker documentation for ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) goes into more detail about what ENTRYPOINT files are and how they work.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2